# Was there anything about cutting up the rabbit that reminded Sean about Leanne?

Tags: plot-explanation, servant

In Episode 1 (Reborn) of Apple TV+ Original *Servant*, Sean is working an a recipe that involves rabbits. He has 2 of them skinned and ready to be cut.

Given what happened before that, we know his mind is busy trying to understand why the new girl is not phased by the fact that she has been hired to look after a doll, and that the mother does not know that her child had died.

Right before he starts to slice the rabbit, and idea comes up in his mind and he starts looking in the new girl's stuff for clues about her.

The question is: What is it about slicing the rabbit that triggered him to do that?
Was it symbolism? was there any link about the rabbits leg (a rabbit's leg is said to bring good luck, is that it?), or was it something else?

I am talking about this point in the episode:
[image: Servant S1E1 - Rabbits]